# C# Building Json string, but I'm getting the error "Invalid anonymous type member declarator"

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm trying to create a Json string like this:

```
{ 
  "StreetLines": [
    "101 Test St",
    "Ste 100"
  ],
  "City": "Dallas",
  "StateOrProvinceCode": "TX",
  "PostalCode": "75999",
  "CountryCode": "US"
}
```

This is my code:

```
var json = new
{
    StreetLines = new
    {
        toAddress1,
        toAddress2
    },
    new
    {
        City = toCity,
        StateOrProvinceCode = toState,
        PostalCode = toZip,
        CountryCode = toCountry
    }
};
```

I'm getting the error "Invalid anonymous type member declarator" for the lower part. I'm not sure what the issue is, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: StreetLines is an array, not an object. Also, remaining properties after StreetLines are supposed to be part of the `json` object. See my post for example.

Comment: It's a compilation error.  Get rid of the `new { }` around the `City = toCity...` sets of properties.  I.e. `var json = new { StreetLines = new [] { toAddress1, toAddress2 }, City = toCity, StateOrProvinceCode = toState, PostalCode = toZip, CountryCode = toCountry }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that `StreetLines` is a JSON array, so you should use a C# array or list:

```
StreetLines = new[] // notice the "[]"
{
    toAddress1,
    toAddress2
},
```

In your JSON, the keys `City`, `StateOrProvinceCode` and so on are *in the same object* as `StreetLines`, so in your C# code you should not create a new anonymous class for them.

If the JSON were like this:

```
{ 
  "StreetLines": [
    "101 Test St",
    "Ste 100"
  ],
  "OtherPartsOfTheAddress": {
    "City": "Dallas",
    "StateOrProvinceCode": "TX",
    "PostalCode": "75999",
    "CountryCode": "US"
  }
}
```

Then you can write

```
var json = new
{
    StreetLines = new[]
    {
        toAddress1,
        toAddress2
    },
    OtherPartsOfTheAddress = new // notice the key name
    {
        City = toCity,
        StateOrProvinceCode = toState,
        PostalCode = toZip,
        CountryCode = toCountry
    }
};
```

But since there is no `OtherPartsOfTheAddress`, you just need to do:

```
var json = new
{
    StreetLines = new[]
    {
        toAddress1,
        toAddress2
    },
    City = toCity,
    StateOrProvinceCode = toState,
    PostalCode = toZip,
    CountryCode = toCountry
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this,

```
var json = new
{
    StreetLines = new List<string>
    {
        toAddress1,
        toAddress2
    },
    City = toCity,
    StateOrProvinceCode = toState,
    PostalCode = toZip,
    CountryCode = toCountry
}
```

StreetLines is a collection of strings and City, Sate, postal etc are part of the main json.